# Proper map, what's wrong?

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, compactness

"A map $f$ from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ is proper if the full preimage of every compact set under $f$ is compact. Prove that every complex polynomial $f$ regarded as a self-map of the plane of complex numbers is a proper map."

$f(z)=a_{0}$ - complex polynomial. Image is one dot - compact set. Preimage - all complex plane. What's wrong?

Comment: it's true only for non-constant polynomials, that's all

Answer (score 1):

In Euclidean space, you can conceptually think of a proper map as one which sends large points to large points. Nonconstant polynomials are an easy example of maps which do this. Constant functions and bounded functions like $\arctan(x)$ are examples of functions which are not proper.

Comment: Thank's. Map is continuous. Preimage of closed set - is closed set. Do we know anything about closed set in Hausdorff's space&

Comment: All compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed. The converse is true iff the entire space is compact.